# Is it correct to compare denominator == 0.0d to prevent division by zero?

Tags: java, double

SonarQube has a [rule](https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS1244) that reports a bug in the following code, stating that "*floating point numbers should not be tested for equality*". Generally this rule is justified, but in this case to me it seems to be a false positive. If it is so, I would like to flag it as such, rather than to work around it using constructs with `Double.compare`, checking intermediate results for `+/-Infinity`, `NaN`, or things like that.

```
public void f(double denominator)
{
    if (denominator == 0.0d)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Division by zero.");

    // code that involves division by denominator ...
}
```

Hence the question: Does the above code throw the `IllegalArgumentException` if and only if division by `denominator` (in expressions containing `double`s only) would lead to `+/-Infinity` or `NaN` intermediate values?

Answer (score 0):

We should avoid test float for equality because of the behavior of representing decimals in binary.

The question you asked is essentially, does the above code work?
Depending on how `f` is used, specifically if you are not explicitly passing in 0.0 as the parameter and instead doing something like `f((0.4-0.1)-0.3)`, it will not catch and divide by a decimal very CLOSE to 0.

P.S. if you want decimal precision, use BigDecimal.